# "/r/ + t + vowel" pronunciation in American English

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

**T** between two vowels in Gen American English (in stressed? or unstressed syllable?) is commonly pronounced as alveolar flap **/ɾ/**. Example words include *better, water, butter, matter* etc.

The /r/ in Gen American English is usually **/ɹ/** as far as I know. So in words like *word, bird, earth* etc, it is **/ɹ/**.

I recently heard some words that end in **rt+vowel** whose pronunciation bewildered me. Words like **[party](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/party)** transcription in the dictionary: **/ˈpɑːr.t̬i/**, the dictionary has given /t̬/ and /r/ in the transcription but when I listen to the pronunciation, it is only /t̬/ (aka flap: **/ɾ/**). And sometimes it sounds as if it has no flap at all and has only **/ɹ/**.

Another example is **[flirty](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flirty)**, whose transcription is: **/ˈflɝː.t̬i/** but there is no **/ɹ/** at all in the pronunciation (although these are dictionary pronunciation, they may not clearly demonstrate the how native speakers pronounce them).

It mostly happens (as I have noticed) when a words ends in **/r/+/t/+vowel**.

So what's really happening here? Is the **/ɹ/** usually dropped? Or is it the flap that is dropped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ears have become too accustomed to British English, and you aren't hearing the "r" in *party* in the dictionary pronunciation, which is obvious to me, an American.

Possibly you don't hear the /r/ in party because it's been absorbed into the /ɑ/ ... it's not an /ɑr/ but an /ɑ˞/, an /r/-colored /ɑ/, where you pronounce the /ɑ/ and the /ɹ/ kind of simultaneously. These are allophones in American English.

The same thing is happening in *flirty* – there's an r-colored /ɜ/. And here, in fact, there's no /r/ in the IPA transcription /ˈflɝː.t̬i/ because they use the symbol /ɝ/, which stands for an r-colored /ɜ/.  Since most Americans use an r-colored vowel in *flirty* and *pertain*, but not in *party*, you generally only see two r-colored phoneme symbols in dictionary transcriptions, /ɝ/ and /ɚ/ (and most dictionaries use /ɜr/ and /ər/, which is less confusing and thus probably a better decision).

Let me say that I use the r-colored vowels /ɝ/, /ɚ/, /ɔ˞/, /ɑ˞/, and /ʊ˞/, but say /ɪr/ and /ɛr/. However, which vowels are r-colored, and which have an /r/ after them varies depending on   the speaker.

Comment: I must admire your ears! (Of course you're a native speaker of American English)

Comment: @Sphinx: My ears are certainly not that good for other languages. For example, I can't hear any difference between the correct pronunciation of Dvořák /dvor̝aːk/ and the. incorrect pronunciation /dvorʒaːk/, despite having a Czech try to tutor me for a few minutes.